# input.outpur error during INSTALLATION

Tags: installation

When start installation ubuntu 12.04 LTS 386 along with windows XP, I get the message {errno 5: input/output error} . I though it was DVD drive failure and i installed a new drive but I still have the same problem, Any suggestion?

Comment: have you checked md5sum (http://askubuntu.com/questions/172947/what-are-the-differences-between-md5sum-and-sha256sum)of the ISO ?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["errno 5 - input/output error" when trying to install](http://askubuntu.com/questions/65830/errno-5-input-output-error-when-trying-to-install)

Answer (score 1):

Input output error means the computer can't read your DVD.
Your DVD is damaged, burn a new one, if possible using a slightly slower speed rate than the last one. Also
 Make sure your DVD drive is clean too, there cleaner CDs that would do this.
Another alternative would be to boot from a Live USB drive.

Comment: I have try all except to boot from usb,Not any result